# ¿Cómo escribir una expresión regular que concatene etiquetas según substrings formados a partir de un patrón, en Python?

Tags: python, regex

Haciendo ejercicios de expresiones regulares me he quedado bastante atascada en el siguiente: Me proponen hacer una función para que dada un string y un segunda substring (que va a hacer de patrón) concatenarle dos "etiquetas".

Ejemplo:

```
parámetro 1:    
“alsikjuyZB8we4 aBBe8XAZ piarBq8 Bq84Z ”

parámetro 2:    
“XYZAB”
```

sustrings formadas sólo por caracteres contenidos en el segundo parámetro:

```
“ZB”, “BB”, “XAZ”, "B", "B", “Z”
```

El resultado es:

```
“alsikjuy[target]ZB[endtarget]8we4 a[target]BB[endtarget]e8[target]XAZ[endtarget] piar[target]B[endtarget]q8 [target]B[endtarget]q84[target]Z[endtarget] ”
```

Mi programa es el siguiente:

```
import re
    def tagger(texto, patron):
        pattern = r"[patron]+"
        texto2 = re.sub(pattern, "[target]"+pattern+"[endtarget]", texto)
        return texto2
```

Soy consciente de que la función está mal y me supongo que es por la sustitución, pero no se como tomar esas pequeñas partes del patrón y concatenarle dichas "etiquetas". Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda o explicación.

Answer (score 4):

Estabas muy cerca, pero hay dos errores importantes de concepto en tu código:

- Cuando haces `pattern = r"[patron]+"` no estás metiendo ahí el patrón que has recibido como parámetro, sino literalmente las letras de la palabra `patron`, por lo que el patrón que buscarías sería aquel compuesto por una o más repeticiones de esas letras (`p`, `a`, `t`, `r`, `o`, `n`).

  Para meter el parámetro puedes hacer uso de las f-strings: `pattern = f"[{patron}]+"` o bien de la función `.format()` o del operador de interpolación de cadenas `%`.
- En la sustitución quieres poner `[target]`/`[endtarget]` alrededor del texto encontrado, pero tú lo estás poniendo alrededor de la cadena contenida en `patron`. Esa cadena es fija, pues es el patrón de búsqueda **pero no el resultado** de esa búsqueda.

  Para hacer lo que quieres  la expresión en el segundo parámetro de `re.sub()` debe contener una marca especial que representa al resultado encontrado por la expresión regular. Esta marca es `\g<0>`. También podrías haber incluido un grupo de captura en el patrón (ponerlo todo entre paréntesis) y usar `\1` para referirte a lo capturado en ese grupo.

En definitiva, con estos cambios tu código quedaría así:

```py
import re
def tagger(texto, patron):
    pattern = f"[{patron}]+"
    texto2 = re.sub(pattern, r"[target]\g<0>[endtarget]", texto)
    return texto2
```

Demostración:

```
>>> tagger("alsikjuyZB8we4 aBBe8XAZ piarBq8 Bq84Z ", "XYZAB")
alsikjuy[target]ZB[endtarget]8we4 a[target]BB[endtarget]e8[target]XAZ[endtarget] piar[target]B[endtarget]q8 [target]B[endtarget]q84[target]Z[endtarget]
```

### Ampliación

La otra opción, la de usar grupos de captura, consiste en utilizar paréntesis dentro del patrón, para marcar qué parte de la expresión regular se quiere capturar porque se va a usar después en el patrón de sustitución. En este ejemplo particular no tiene mucho sentido, porque queremos que la captura sea el patrón completo. Aún así podría hacerse de este modo:

```
def tagger(texto, patron):
    pattern = f"([{patron}]+)"
    texto2 = re.sub(pattern, r"[target]\1[endtarget]", texto)
    return texto2
```

El patrón lleva un `(` al inicio y un `)` al final, por lo que todo él es un grupo de captura (y el único en este caso, en otros casos más generales podrían aparecer más paréntesis, incluso anidados, dentro del patrón y serían grupos adicionales).

En la expresión de sustitución se usa `\1` para referirse al primer grupo capturado (`\2` al segundo si hubiera, etc.)

Un ejemplo de cómo ésto puede ser útil. Imagina que queremos buscar y reemplazar las mismas subcadenas, pero *sólo si llevan un 8 detrás*. En este caso el patrón a buscar serí a `[XYZAB]+8`, pero el 8 no queremos reemplazarlo, por lo que el grupo de captura dejaría al 8 fuera. Entonces sería así:

```
    pattern = "([XYZAB]+)8"
    texto2 = re.sub(pattern, r"[target]\1[endtarget]", texto)
```

Comment: Wow!!! Es cierto, no conocía que existía una forma para acceder a los resultados de los patrones. Mi única duda es el último apunte que aclaró, respecto al paréntesis. Se refiere a hacer grupos en el patrón, me imagino, Si no, y no le es mucha molestia, ¿podría explicarlo?

Comment: @CandelaCand Hecho. He ampliado la respuesta con una explicación. Mira a ver si es esto lo que preguntabas.